# How do i get actual position of object in a list

Tags: python, list

How do I get the actual position of an object in a list?

```
my_list = [0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, False, 0]

for i in my_list:
    if i == False:
        print('my list:', my_list, 'object:', i, 'At Position', my_list.index(i))
```

Comment: does your code not work as expected?

Comment: Hmmm... that's fetching all the indexes of ```0```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, checking equality isn't enough. In Python, running `0 == False` returns `True`. This is exacerbated by the fact that your list contains elements of objects of different types, and `0` is at the start of your list. So, if you want to find `False` here, you should check the element type as well:

```py
my_list = [0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, False, 0]

for idx,i in enumerate(my_list):
    if type(i) is bool and i == False:
        print('my list:', my_list, 'object:', i, 'At Position', idx)
```

Output:

```
my list: [0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, False, 0] object: False At Position 7
```

#### Edit:

As o11c mentioned below, `False` provides a special scenario where using `is` for checking its equality here is valid, since `False` is [one of few built-in singletons in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html). Therefore `if i is False` will work for the conditional statement:

```py
if i is False:
    print('my list:', my_list, 'object:', i, 'At Position', idx)
```

Comment: or just `is False` since bool is a singleton. Well, doubleton.

Comment: @o11c I think it's a good point. However it won't work the other way around, will it? For example, finding numerical elements (say 0) while `False` is in the list. But for this case, it's definitely a clean Pythonic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 2 things that will help:

1. `enumerate` function. This will return a counter. More about this: [Enumerate Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
2. By checking the type of the element, you can get your expected result. A `False` Value is actually expressed by `0`. So, all `0` are printed. Also, the first appearance of `0` is at index `0`. So, it is printing that every time. `type()` will get the data type of the element. Since `type(i) is bool` means if it is `True/False`. This will give you the result.

```
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    if j == False and type(j) is bool:
        print('my list:', my_list, 'object:', j, 'At Position', i)
```

You can also use `if j is False:` as a `boolean` is single.

Comment: Are you sure `my_list.index(j)` is correct? That's not going to return `i` in OP's case.

Comment: code doesn't get the actual position of all FALSE objects

Comment: Ohh, Thanks! @MZ, I edited my answer.  It should be ```print('my list:', my_list, 'object:', j, 'At Position', i)```

Comment: code not fetching all the FALSE object positions in the list

Comment: @Seun you only have one `False` object, is it fetching none?

Comment: print(int(0) == False) so 0 in the list is also FALSE

Comment: Works on my machine ```my list: [0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, False, 0] object: False At Position 7```

Comment: @Seun do you *want* to find `0`? If you want to find `0`, don't check the `type`, and clarify your question.